# Separable Commutative $C*$ algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, commutative-algebra, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Consider the algebra $C(X)$ of continuous complex functions over a compact space $X$. On what conditions this algebra is separable?

What if $X$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$?